# C# Proxy with username and password

Tags: c#, proxy

I set up a proxy instance and used it with a webrequest object.

```
        WebProxy a = new WebProxy("ip:port", true);
        proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        WebRequest b = WebRequest.Create("webpage url");
        b.Proxy = proxy;

        WebResponse c = req.GetResponse();

        StreamReader d = new StreamReader(c.GetResponseStream());

        d.ReadToEnd();//web page source
```

Works as it should, but I want to display the page in a web browser control without loss of information and design. If I set my control's document text to the source that was just downloaded. It has very bad formatting.

edit: Is there a way for me to apply the proxy object to the web browser control itself?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to with proxy or name or password. A modern web page is a collection of a number of files, stylesheets, javascript, images, you name it and they all affect what the page looks like. It's not going to work the way you are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

**edit** The WebBrowser control just uses IE's settings, so you don't have to set the proxy yourself. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/f4dc3550-f213-41ff-a17d-95c917bed027/ how to set the IE proxy in code.

---

Well the problem here is that the HTML that you've received via the `WebRequest` contains relative paths to the CSS files that are not present in the current context. You can modify the HTML, by adding the following tag in the `<head>` section:

```
<base href="http://domainname.com/" />
```

After that the WebBrowser control resolves the relative CSS paths to the domain in this tag.

Comment: Works, but I need everything to run through the proxy. So its a no go.

Comment: That doesnt help for usernames and passwords