# C# webrequest or webclient issue

Tags: c#, webrequest

I am implementing a forum board into my application.
The page is downloaded with a webrequest object, then applied it to the document text of a web browser control (must access the page through webrequest) and there is elements and normal advertisements missing. how can I fix this?

This is the function I am using:

```
        private void Navigate(string url, string credentials, ref WebBrowser wbBrowser)
        {
            WebRequest req;

            WebProxy proxy;

            WebResponse response;

            StreamReader sr;

            int index;

            string  username,
                    password,
                    ipAddress,
                    temp;


            index = 0;

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    index = credentials.IndexOf(':', index + 1);

                if (index != -1)
                {
                    ipAddress = credentials.Remove(index, credentials.Length - index);

                    temp = credentials.Remove(0, index + 1);

                    index = temp.IndexOf(':');

                    username = temp.Remove(index, temp.Length - index);
                    password = temp.Remove(0, index + 1);

                    proxy = new WebProxy(ipAddress, true);
                    proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

                    req = WebRequest.Create(url);
                    req.Proxy = proxy;

                    response = req.GetResponse();


                    sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                    temp = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    index = temp.IndexOf("<head>");

                    if (index != -1)
                        temp = temp.Insert(index + 6, "<base href=\"" + url + " \" />");

                    mainDocument = null;

                    wbBrowser.DocumentText = temp;

                    while (mainDocument == null)
                        Thread.Sleep(250);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I use it as Navigate("page", "ip:port:username:password", ref demoBrowser)

Comment: Show the code you used for generating the webRequest/Response?

Answer (score 0):

I'll quote myself from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029149/c-proxy-with-username-and-password), because it makes perfect sense when not dealing with proxies:

Well the problem here is that the HTML that you've received via the WebRequest contains relative paths to the CSS files that are not present in the current context. You can modify the HTML, by adding the following tag in the  section:

```
<base href="http://domainname.com/" />
```

After that the WebBrowser control resolves the relative CSS paths to the domain in this tag.

Comment: Yes it does show the styles, but the adsense blocks I have at the bottom of my forum are missing completely from the source code. Thats what I need help with now.

Comment: Any idea how to get that up and running?